# How to create buckets with the same number of elements from a pandas dataframe with 2 indices and a score?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, optimization, discrete-mathematics

I have a dataframe with 3 levels:

- index "users_A"
- index "users_B"
- score, an integer for each (user_a x user_b)

We cannot attribute a user_B to a user_A if the score is 0

The idea is to drop duplicated user_b to create a partition of all user_b where we maximize the minimum number of user_b attributed to a user_a. The score should be the decision criteria but there is a lot of duplicates and I end up with no available user_b for my last users.

Example:
Here, from the dataset input, I want a function to get the dataset output

```
import pandas as pd
import random

#This code will generate a dataframe similar to mine
users_A = [0, 1, 2]
users_B = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']
input = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([users_A, users_B], names=['users_A', 'users_B']))
input["scores"] = pd.Series([random.randrange(0, 11) for i in range(18)] , index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([users_A, users_B]))
input = input[input.scores %2 !=0 ]
print(input)

>>>
                 scores
users_A users_B        
0       a             7
        b             7
        d             7
1       a             9
        b             3
        e             5
        f             5
2       a             1
        b             1
        c             1
        e             3
        f             7
```

From this input I want an output without duplicate where every user_A get at least 2 user_B because it is possible, and to maximize the sum of scores per user_A

The output is:

```
>>>
                 scores
users_A users_B        
0       a             7
        d             7
1       b             3
        e             5
2       c             1
        f             7
```

(I maximized the sum per hand, maybe it is not the optimal solution but it shows what kind of partition I want)

Any clue on how to tackle this problem?? I see a solution where I compute all the possible partitions and after that select the most balanced but I have a big pool of users and I want to deploy this -- for internal tooling, but it should compute the res in seconds...

Thanks!!!

Comment: I find it hard to understand how users_B are allocated to users_A. Why do 'a', and 'd' get assigned to users_A[0] and 'b','e' to users_A[1]? What's the logic?

Comment: I just did that by hand I tried to allocate the first users_B a bit randomly and then I proceeded by elimination